# Could not copy native binaries to temp directory Kinesis KPL

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to build a simple application that will produce messages to Kinesis using the KPL.  I am writing this in scala and am receiving an error message that I can't seem to figure out.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.{KinesisProducer, KinesisProducerConfiguration}

object KinesisStream extends App{
  ProduceToKinesis()

  def ProduceToKinesis(): Unit ={

    val config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
    val kinesis = new KinesisProducer(config)
    val data = ByteBuffer.wrap("myData".getBytes("UTF-8"))

    kinesis.addUserRecord("TestStream", "myPartitionKey", data)
  }
}
```

it fails at

```
val kinesis = new KinesisProducer(config)
```

with an error message of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy native binaries to temp directory C:\Users\************\AppData\Local\Temp\amazon-kinesis-producer-native-binaries
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer.extractBinaries(KinesisProducer.java:844)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer.<init>(KinesisProducer.java:242)
    at KinesisStream$.ProduceToKinesis(KinesisStream.scala:14)
    at KinesisStream$.delayedEndpoint$KinesisStream$1(KinesisStream.scala:9)
    at KinesisStream$delayedInit$body.apply(KinesisStream.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at KinesisStream$.main(KinesisStream.scala:8)
    at KinesisStream.main(KinesisStream.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:462)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer.extractBinaries(KinesisProducer.java:803)
    ... 18 more
```

My Build.SBT looks like this:

```
name := "Kinesis"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-producer" % "0.12.1"
```

Comment: for reference: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/issues/73

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been long since this issue was posted. But recently I fell into the same issue and couldn't find much on the web. Fortunately I'v found the solution, this could be helpful to someone else wandering for the fix.
It's a version issue as mentioned here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/issues/113#issuecomment-345028662. It worked for me when downgraded the KPL version to 0.13.1

Here's the pom dependency worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```